is $(\ker(A-\lambda I)^k\setminus\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-1})\cup\{\mathbf{0}\}$ a subspace?
Given that $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3$ are linearly independent vectors in $\ker(A-\lambda I)^k$ but not in $\ker(A - \lambda I)^{k-1}$ for some $\lambda$ and $k \geq 2$, how can it be proven that any possible linear combination of these vectors will also not be in $\ker(A - \lambda I)^{k-1}$? Therefore, more generally, that
$$\left(\ker(A-\lambda I)^k\setminus\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}\right)\cup\{\mathbf{0}\}$$is a subspace?
This question emerged when I was trying to prove that any set of jordan chains is linearly independent (if the top vectors also were linearly independent), once I got stuck, I found some posts that went through an analogous approach I did but at a certain point they concluded something like $$(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}(a_1\mathbf{v}_1 + a_2\mathbf{v}_2 + a_3\mathbf{v}_3) = 0 \implies a_1,a_2,a_3=0$$ which wasn't very obvious to me.

The set difference of two subspaces is never a subspace because it does not contain the zero vector.

It's not closed under addition.  Let $A$ be the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue, and $A^2=0$.  Take $v_1=[1,3]^T$ and $v_2=[1,-3]^T$
Then $v_1,v_2 \in\ker(A^2),\notin \ker A$, but $v_1+v_2 \in\ker(A)$.

Then, the final conclusion on posts like this, in the part it says that "$a_i=0$ for each $i$ is required" is not necessarily true?

@excitedGoose As best I can tell, either you are mixing up / and , or you're mixing up set complements with complementary subspaces.  Needless to say, this answer in no way applies to that one.
